# "Access Denied" during a successful Git push

Tags: git, ssh, tortoisegit, centos5

I always get an "Access Denied" during a git push to remote, even though the push works fine.

This is using Tortoise Git from a Windows box. Our server is Centos 5.4 integrated with our Windows Active Directory domain using winbind with automatic user creation - which seems to work well. The repositories are under a 'git' user which shares a group with the 'staff' which are created by winbind. Umask 002 on the repositories allows new files to be shared correctly. As far as I can see the group permissions work fine.

I'm presuming it's some non-critical git function like logging which is failing but I am worried it will come back to bite me one day. I've searched for log entries but can't find anything to lead me to what's being denied.

```
git.exe  push --progress  "origin-pip.jones" master:master

Counting objects: 30, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19)
Writing objects: 100% (19/19)
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 2.07 KiB, done.
Access denied

To  ssh://pip.jones@svn.ourdomain.com/var/git/repositories/Products/Product.git
4b3e259..8fe7b0a  master -> master
Success
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does adding `-v` add anything helpful?

Comment: Is it possible this is a message emitted by a pre-receive hook on the server?

Comment: I can't add -v in Tortoise Git as it doesn't appear to have a GUI option for it. But this made me think of trying the Windows Git Bash - which doesn't error. I've also tried using Git Extensions and this doesn't display the error either. So it appears to be a Tortoise-specific issue.